# Variable Encapsulation in Case Statement

Tags: abap

While modifying an existing program's CASE statement, I had to add a second block where some logic is repeated to set NetWeaver portal settings. This is done by setting values in a local variable, then assigning that variable to a Changing parameter. I copied over the code and did a Pretty Print, expecting to compiler to complain about the unknown variable. To my surprise however, this code actually compiles just fine:

```
CASE i_actionid.
    WHEN 'DOMIGO'.
        DATA:   ls_portal_actions  TYPE powl_follow_up_sty.
        CLEAR ls_portal_actions.
        ls_portal_actions-bo_system = 'SAP_ECC_Common'.
        " [...]
        c_portal_actions = ls_portal_actions.
    WHEN 'EBELN'.
        ls_portal_actions-bo_system = 'SAP_ECC_Common'.
        " [...]
        C_PORTAL_ACTIONS = ls_portal_actions.
ENDCASE.
```

As I have seen in every other programming language, the `DATA:` declaration in the first `WHEN` statement should be encapsulated and available only inside that switch block. Does SAP ignore this encapsulation to make that value available in the entire CASE statement? Is this documented anywhere?

Note that this code compiles just fine and double-clicking the local variable in the second switch takes me to the data declaration in the first. I have however not been able to test that this code executes properly as our testing environment is down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short you cannot do this. You will have the following scopes in an abap program within which to declare variables (from local to global):

- Form routine: all variables between FORM and ENDFORM
- Method: all variables between METHOD and ENDMETHOD
- Class - all variables between CLASS and ENDCLASS but only in the CLASS DEFINITION section
- Function module: all variables between FUNCTION and ENDFUNCTION
- Program/global - anything not in one of the above is global in the current program including variables in PBO and PAI modules

Having the ability to define variables locally in a for loop or if is really useful but unfortunately not possible in ABAP. The closest you will come to publicly available documentation on this is on help.sap.com: [Local Data in the Subroutine](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_47x200/helpdata/en/d3/2e974d35c511d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm)

As for the compile process do not assume that ABAP will optimize out any variables you do not use it won't, use the code inspector to find and remove them yourself. Since ABAP works the way it does I personally define all my variables at the start of a modularization unit and not inline with other code and have gone so far as to  modify the pretty printer to move any inline definitions to the top of the current scope.

Comment: You modified the pretty printer to move data declarations?  That's awesome.  Don't suppose you've shared that code anywhere, scn, etc?

Comment: Thanks for this helpful overview, it's a shame that this isn't better documented in the training and help material. I'll second Bryain's request for that Pretty Print modification, assuming you're able to release that publicly.

Comment: Unfortunately did it at work so I'm not at liberty to share it but it was pretty straight forward I added an exit right at the end of function module PRETTY_PRINTER before ENDFUCTION. If you add a call here you can use the table ntext[] which contains the formatted source code (just check l_indentation_wrong which if 'X' indicates syntax errors in which case I did not do my formatting). It also runs for the new Eclipse ABAP editor

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption that a `CASE` statement defines its own scope of variables in ABAP is simply wrong (and would be wrong for a number of other programming languages as well). It's a bad idea to litter your code with variable declarations because that makes it awfully hard to read and to maintain, but it is possible. The `DATA` statements - as well as many other declarative statements - are only evaluated at compile time and are completely ignored at runtime. You can find [more information about the scopes in the online documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/EN/fc/eb3034358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/frameset.htm).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the compile process? As I understand it ABAP is not really compiled but rather optimized for interpretation on activation. So does the compiler simply check whether every variable used is declared earlier in the code as well as perform static type enforcement? When you say that declarative statements are ignored at runtime, does that mean that no dynamic type checking is performed?

Comment: If you have any references on this subject they'd be very much appreciated. The TAW books I have seem largely useless and I can find little to no reliable information about the compile/interpretation process on the web.

Comment: @Lilienthal: There is very little information available. ABAP is compiled into a kind of bytecode (called "load" for historical reasons) that is then interpreted by a virtual machine in the kernel. This load is optimized for a certain machine type (in contrast to Java bytecode which is system-independent). You won't need much more information than that because there's no way to interact with the load as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

The inline variable declarations are now possible with the newest version of SAP Netweaver. Here is the link to the documentation [DATA - inline declaration](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abendata_inline.htm). Here are also some [guidelines](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abendeclaration_inline_guidl.htm) of a good and bad usage of this new feature

Here is a quote from this site:

> A declaration expression with the declaration operator DATA declares a variable var used as an operand in the current writer position. The declared variable is visible statically in the program from DATA(var) and is valid in the current context. The declaration is made when the program is compiled, regardless of whether the statement is actually executed.

Personally have not had time to check it out yet, because of lack of access to such system.

Comment: The new features are great we have to support customers on multiple release 4.7 -> latest so we can never use them :( wish SAP would backport once in a while